# /icons/icomoon.woff files 404 not found in Cloudways

Tags: css, http-status-code-404, woff, woff2, cloudways

I can't see the icomoon icons in production because it returns a 404 error:

GET /icons/icomoon.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET /icons/icomoon.woff2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

THE FILES ARE IN THE RIGHT ROUTE: public/icons

I have the following code in public/icons/style.css:

```
font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:
    url('icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('icomoon.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

I've tried to put the src this way:

```
  src: url('icomoon.woff') format('woff');
  src: url('icomoon.woff2') format('woff2');
```

But it didn't work.

I've also tried to put the following code in public/web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
```

And it also din't work.

Comment: The font is not there on this location `public/icons/icomoon.woff` download these and place there

Comment: They are in the right location public/icons

Comment: Give a slash before the path `url('/icomoon.woff')`

Comment: It still does not work with a slash before the path.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, Cloudways has disabled the execution of .woff files by default. All I had to do is open a ticket and ask them to enable it.